# How to create an index for elements of an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, indexing

With this schema:

```
create table object (
   obj_id      serial      primary key,
   name        varchar(80) not null unique,
   description text,
   tag_arr     int[]
);

create table tag (
   tag_id      serial      primary key,
   label       varchar(20) not null unique
);
```

An object may have any number of tags attached. Instead of an `object X tag` table, I wish to keep `tag_id`s in an array so they can be easily fetched with the object record.

How do I create an index on `object` so that each element of `tar_arr` is an index?

That said, are there better ways to solve this problem?

#### Discussion

This could be achieved with:

```
create table obj_x_tag(
   obj_id    references object,
   tag_id    references tag,
   constraint obj_x_tag_pk primary key( obj_id, tag_id )
);

select obj_id, name, description, array_agg( tag_id )
from object o
join obj_x_tag x using( obj_id )
group by 1, 2;
```

But to me it makes more sense to simply keep the array of `tag_id`s in a column and dispense with the cross table and `array_agg()`

It was suggested to use [PostgresQL SQL: Converting results to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723851/postgresql-sql-converting-results-to-array). The problem, as noted, is that "this doesn't actually index individual array values, but instead indexes the entire array"

It was also suggested to use pg's `intarr` and `gist` (or `gin`) index. The problem - to me - seems that the index is for the standard pg set-based array operators, *not* necessarily optimized for finding *one* element of an array, but rather where one array *contains* another, *intersects* with another - for me it's counter-intuitive that, size-wise and speed-wise, such a wide solution is correct for such a narrow problem. Also, the `intarr` extension seems limited to `int`, not covering `int64` or `char`, limiting its usefulness.

Comment: You should use GIN check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns

Comment: Go for a normalized model and store that information in a table containing the `obj_id` and the `tag_id` that will save you a lot of trouble in the long run. Just think of a query that gives you the number how often a tag was used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name _really_ don't want to get into a back and forth, but seems to me that, if each element of an array were indexed, then things like "a query that gives you the number how often a tag was used" would be the same cost as a cross table (which is really just an index table itself).

Comment: @JoseP - thanks for the link.  addressed using GIN in added Discussion part of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create GIN indexes on any 1-dimensional array with standard Postgres.
[Details in the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) (last chapter).

While operating with **`integer`** arrays (plain `int4`, not `int2` or `int8` and no `NULL` values) the [additional supplied module **`intarray`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) provides a lot more operators and typically superior performance. Install it (once per database) with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

You can create GIN or GIST indexes on integer arrays. There are [examples in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.28.7)
[`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. For older versions you need to run the supplied script.

Comment: you are really good - thanks again.  looked at `intarr` and do not know that it is correct - have placed my notes in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional solution would be to use a table of tags and a many-many between tag and object. Then you can index the tag table and pull everything in a single select statement via a join. If you're not happy with the programming model, check out your local friendly ORM vendor.

I'm not a PostgreSQL expert by any means, but this doesn't seem like a good use case for arrays.

Comment: agree that a cross table between object and tag is the classical solution - indeed my current solution.  but in this case a cross table is expensive and cumbersome for something very light weight.  if arrays could be indexed, then seems to me it would be a good solution, despite the lack of RI.

Comment: @ccyoung: why is a cross table "expensive". Using tables to store data is what relational databases are made for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am somewhat of a database bigot, as I suspect you probably are.  but I also like many of non-classical elements such as nested tables and using `array_agg()` function to pull in using one row when the child rows are trivial.  to me this makes sense and makes life easier. have expanded question to give better examples.

Comment: @ccyoung: just think of a query that shows the count how often each tag was used. That'll be utterly complex with an array but a very easy with a normalized model. Also finding objects that have two or three specific tags will be a lot easier as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  `select count(1) from obj where 123456 = ANY( tag_arr )` - if `tag_arr` elements are indexed, it would be efficient as well

Comment: @ccyoung: Now get that count for all tags (piece of cake using a group by). But apparently you do want to find a workaround for a problem that you wouldn't have if you used a normalized model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The problem with many-many tables is per-row over head in most RDBMSes is very large. In Postgres, it's at minimum 24 bytes. The overhead on a 1D array is 8 bytes *for the entire array*. That makes a huge difference. Generating the complete set is easy using unnest().

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround, because I see **no PostgreSQL optimized internal function** for do the same,

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION unnest_with_idx(anyarray) RETURNS 
table(idx integer, val anyelement) AS $$ 
   SELECT generate_series(1,array_upper($1,1)) as idx, unnest($1) as val;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
-- Test:
SELECT idx,val from unnest_with_idx(array[1,20,3,5]) as t;
```

For check if exists an internal function, see "[How to acess array internal index with postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12246738/287948)" question.

---

Edited after @JimNasby comment

### Solution for pg9.4+

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(array[20,11,3,5]) WITH ORDINALITY;
```

the `WITH ORDINALITY`  produces a new column "ordinality" that is the array-index. See also [this tutorial](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-with-ordinality/).

In **pg9.5+**, it works fine also for JSON arrays!

```
 SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements( '[20,11,3,5]'::JSONB ) WITH ORDINALITY
```

Comment: You can now use the WITH ORDINALITY option: SELECT * FROM unnest(array) WITH ORDINALITY;. Not sure what version added that though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create index with `gin__int_ops`

```
create index on initial_costs using gin (parking_ids gin__int_ops);
```

and use `@>` operator

```
explain analyse SELECT
    initial_costs.id,
    parking_ids
FROM initial_costs
where  initial_costs.parking_ids @> array[9459];


QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on initial_costs  (cost=5.12..108.41 rows=93 width=21) (actual time=0.034..0.095 rows=37 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (parking_ids @> '{9459}'::integer[])
  Heap Blocks: exact=26
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on initial_costs_parking_ids_idx3  (cost=0.00..5.09 rows=93 width=0) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=37 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (parking_ids @> '{9459}'::integer[])
Planning Time: 0.192 ms
Execution Time: 0.124 ms
```