# How to access array internal index with postgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

This is my (perhaps usual for you) **non-optimized** solution:

Workaround for PG problem with non-optimized internal function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION unnest_with_idx(anyarray)
RETURNS TABLE(idx integer, val anyelement) AS
$$ 
   SELECT generate_series(1,array_upper($1,1)) as idx, unnest($1) as val;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Test:

```sql
SELECT idx,val from unnest_with_idx(array[1,20,3,5]) as t;
```

But, as I said, *non-optimized*. I can't believe (!!) that PostgreSQL doesn't have an internal index for arrays ... ? But in this case, the question is how to directly access this index, where the [GIN-like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4058731/287948) internal counter?

NOTE1: the solution above and the question is not the same as "[how do you create an index by each element of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867577/287948)". Also not the same as "[Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4058731/287948)" because the function is for an isolated array, not for a table index for array fields.

---

NOTE2 (edited after answers): "array indexes" (more popular term) or "array subscripts"  or "array counter" are terms that we can use in a semantic path to refer the "internal counter", the accumulator to the next array item. I see that ***no PostgreSQL command** offer a direct access to this counter*.  As `generate_series()` function, the `generate_subscripts()` function is a **sequence generator**, and the performance is (best but) near the same.  By other hand `row_number()` function offers a direct access to a "internal counter of rows", but it is about rows, *not about arrays*, and unfortunately the performance is worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Postgres 9.4 or later

While operating with 1-dimensional arrays and standard index subscripts (like almost always), use the new [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) instead:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[1,20,3,5]) WITH ORDINALITY t(val, idx);
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Just make sure you don't trip over non-standard subscripts. See:

- [Normalize array subscripts so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-so-they-start-with-1)

### Postgres 9.3 or earlier

(Original answer.)

Postgres *does* provide dedicated functions to [generate array subscripts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS):

```sql
WITH   x(a) AS (VALUES ('{1,20,3,5}'::int[]))
SELECT generate_subscripts(a, 1) AS idx
     , unnest(a) AS val
FROM   x;
```

Effectively it does almost the same as @Frank's query, just without subquery.
Plus, it also works for subscripts that do not start with `1`.

Either solution works for *1-dimensional* arrays only! (Can easily be expanded to multiple dimensions.)

Function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_with_idx(anyarray) 
  RETURNS TABLE(idx integer, val anyelement)
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
  SELECT generate_subscripts($1, 1), unnest($1);
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest_with_idx('{1,20,3,5}'::int[]);
```

Also consider:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest_with_idx('[4:7]={1,20,3,5}'::int[]);
```

About custom array subscripts:

- [Normalize array subscripts so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-so-they-start-with-1)

To get normalized subscripts starting with 1 for a 1-dimensional array:

```
SELECT generate_series(1, array_length($1,1)) ...
```

That's almost the query you had already, just with [`array_length()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead of `array_upper()` - which would fail with non-standard subscripts.

##### Performance

I ran a quick test on an array of 1000 int with all queries presented here so far. They all perform about the same (~ 3,5 ms) - except for `row_number()` on a subquery (~ 7,5 ms) - as expected, because of the subquery.

Comment: Thanks!  Well, there are two new solutions after *generate_series()*... What is the fasted: *row_number()* or *generate_subscripts()*?

Comment: @PeterKrauss It depends on your use case (I mean test it with your data).  `generate_subscripts()` is much more readable for me.  I won't expect much difference when used on arrays of normal size, however.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I added an alternative solution, plus results of a quick performance test.

Comment: Ok, comparing `explain analyse` times with the "SELECT 1, unnest($1)" time, I have subscripts=109%, series=111%, and row_number 150%. Your solution with `generate_subscripts()` is the best (!), and my solution with `generate_series()`  is not so wrong.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: You were actually very close to begin with.

Comment: To reader: the `WITH ORDINALITY`  is perfect!  In pg9.5 it works fine also with JSON and JSONB arrays!  `SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements( '[20,11,3,5]'::JSONB ) WITH ORDINALITY`

Answer (score 1):

[row_number()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) works:

```
SELECT 
    row_number() over(), 
    value
FROM (SELECT unnest(array[1,20,3,5])) a(value);
```

Then, the optimized function will be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_with_idx(anyarray) 
RETURNS table(idx integer, val anyelement) AS $$ 
  SELECT (row_number() over())::integer as idx, val
  FROM (SELECT unnest($1)) a(val);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to keep the order?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I didn't test it, and without a sort order, there is no guarantee

Comment: Yes! I am testing, and I think array order is always preserved.  Thank a lot, it is the solution.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I've approved your edit. Note that you could also answer you own question ([see this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking))

Comment: Wouldn't this fail for arrays with non-standard subscripts like `'[4:7]={1,20,3,5}'::int[]`?

Comment: Sorry, I changed my "chosen answer": my benchmark of percentual times with row_number (150%), generate_subscripts (109%) and generate_series (111%) demonstrates that row_number is the  worst (!), and that generate_subscripts the faster, then it near to me need of "internal array index" and optimization.