# Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, unnest, set-returning-functions

I understand that using

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[5,3,9]) as id
```

without an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the result set is not guaranteed. I could for example get:

```
id
--
3
5
9
```

But what about the following request:

```
SELECT
  unnest(ARRAY[5,3,9]) as id,
  unnest(ARRAY(select generate_series(1, array_length(ARRAY[5,3,9], 1)))) as idx
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

Is it guaranteed that the 2 `unnest()` calls (which have the same length) will unroll in parallel and that the index `idx` will indeed match the position of the item in the array?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is a feature of Postgres and parallel unnesting is ***guaranteed*** to be in sync (as long as all arrays have the same number of elements).
**Postgres 9.4 adds a clean solution for parallel unnest:**

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

The order of resulting rows is not guaranteed, though. Actually, with a statement as simple as:

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[5,3,9]) AS id;
```

the resulting order of rows is "guaranteed", but Postgres does not assert anything. The query optimizer is free to order rows as it sees fit as long as the order is not explicitly defined. This may have side effects in more complex queries.

If the second query in your question is what you actually want (add an index number to unnested array elements), there is a better way with [**generate_subscripts()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS):

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[5,3,9]) AS id
     , generate_subscripts(ARRAY[5,3,9], 1) AS idx
ORDER  BY idx;
```

Details in this related answer:

- [How to access array internal index with postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246738/how-to-access-array-internal-index-with-postgresql/12250006#12250006)

You will be interested in [**`WITH ORDINALITY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) in Postgres **9.4**:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[5,3,9]) WITH ORDINALITY tbl(id, idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No, `idx` will not match the array positions, when accepting the premise that `unnest()` output may be randomly ordered.

**Demo**:
since the current implementation of `unnest` actually output the rows in the order of elements, I suggest to add a layer on top of it to simulate a random order:

```
CREATE FUNCTION unnest_random(anyarray)  RETURNS setof anyelement
language sql as
$$ select unnest($1) order by random() $$;
```

Then check out a few executions of your query with `unnest` replaced by `unnest_random`:

```
SELECT
  unnest_random(ARRAY[5,3,9]) as id,
  unnest_random(ARRAY(select generate_series(1, array_length(ARRAY[5,3,9], 1)))) as idx
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

Example of output:

```
 id | idx 
----+-----
  3 |   1
  9 |   2
  5 |   3
```

`id=3` is associated with `idx=1` but `3` was in 2nd position in the array. It's all wrong.

**What's wrong in the query**: it assumes that the first `unnest` will shuffle the elements using the same permutation as the second `unnest` (permutation in the mathematic sense: the relationship between order in the array and order of the rows). But this assumption contradicts the premise that the order output of `unnest` is unpredictable to start with.

**About this question**:

> Is it guaranteed that the 2 unnest() calls (which have the same
>   length) will unroll in parallel

In `select unnest(...) X1, unnest(...) X2`, with `X1` and `X2` being of type `SETOF something` and having the same number of rows, `X1` and `X2` will be paired in the final output so that the `X1` value at row `N` will face the `X2` value at the same row `N`.
(it's a kind of UNION for columns, as opposed to a cartesian product).

But I wouldn't describe this pairing as *unroll in parallel*, so I'm not sure this is what you meant.

Anyway this pairing doesn't help with the problem since it happens after the unnest calls have lost the array positions.

**An alternative**: In [this thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1371724857304-5760087.post@n5.nabble.com) from the pgsql-sql mailing list, this function is suggested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_with_ordinality(anyarray, OUT value
anyelement, OUT ordinality integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$$
SELECT $1[i], i FROM
    generate_series(array_lower($1,1),
                    array_upper($1,1)) i;
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Based on this, we can order by the second output column:

```
select * from unnest_with_ordinality(array[5,3,9]) order by 2;
```

```
 value | ordinality 
-------+------------
     5 |          1
     3 |          2
     9 |          3
```

**With postgres 9.4 and above**: The `WITH ORDINALITY` clause that can follow SET RETURNING function calls will provide this functionality in a generic way.

Comment: Your example is a red herring. It doesn't proof what you claim it would. Your function `unnest_random()` orders rows by `random()` *before* pairing with the second SRF. If you unnest two arrays in parallel, the sort order is pre-determined and pairing is *guaranteed*. You are `accepting the premise that unnest() output may be randomly ordered.`, but that's just not the case in the current implementation. The correct answer to the question is "Yes".

Comment: That premise comes from the question. To me it's asking if the proposed query with its pairing technique insulates from a potentially non-ordered output from `unnest`. So no, it doesn't. That said, the current implementation of unnest follows the array order. The trouble is that it's undocumented. Personally I don't have a problem with that, but if the OP does, I can't blame him for that.

Comment: As I understand it 1/ that the current impl of unnest does the unnesting in the array order (not random); 2/ that for parallel unnest, the pairing is guaranteed to be done in sequence on the base of the unnested arrays; that I may get unordered tuples because of the optimizer. So you are both right that I should switch to 9.4 ;-) but Erwin's answer is the confirmation that I was looking for regarding the pairing (my non-ordered point was coming from things I had read and mis-understood at the time about the optimizer stage)