# Postgres: convert array of elements to multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using a query along with the functions available in postgres such as `string_to_array` and `string_agg`, data from raw tables are converted to following results set.

```
id, text
001, {foo,boo,foo}
002, {"",for,test,friday}
003, {"","",test,friday,tuesday,foo,boo}
```

Here id is id of a person and text is actually type of array. Now what I am trying to do is generate following structure.

```
id, text, text_count
001, foo, 2
001, boo, 1
002, test, 1
002, friday, 1
```

This is the query I used to get my existing format that I have mentioned, but how can I enhance this query to get the id, text, text_count results.

```
select id, string_to_array(string_agg(b.text,' '), ' ') as words
from tableA a,tableB b group by id
```

I would also like to get rid of data with "", I believe they are empty strings in postgres but not really sure.

Comment: You are trying to get a count, grouping by id and text? What does your raw data look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`unnest()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).
Assuming `id` to be unique:

```
SELECT id, txt, count(*) As txt_count
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , unnest(txt) AS txt
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  txt <> ''
GROUP  BY id, txt
ORDER  BY id, txt;
```

`txt` instead of `text`, because I never use basic type names as identifiers.
The condition `WHERE  txt <> ''` removes both empty stings (`''`) as well as `NULL` values.

When unnesting an array, you get as many rows in the result set as there are elements in the array. Careful, when unnesting multiple arrays in parallel:
[Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)
[Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)

There is a cleaner syntax variant in Postgres 9.3+ for this with a `LATERAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, txt, count(*) As txt_count
FROM  (
   SELECT id, x.txt
   FROM   tbl t, unnest(t.txt) x(txt)
   ) sub
WHERE  txt <> ''
GROUP  BY id, txt
ORDER  BY id, txt;
```

Details here:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08ffe/1)

Comment: Can I used my query inside values where because all my query does is spit out those values.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: I added a cleaner form using a table instead of the VALUES expression (which was just a quick substitute for the actual table). And a fiddle.

Comment: So I don't need to use string_to_array(string_agg(b.text,' '), ' ')? because without that query i don't have the data that I need to use for the query that you have mentioned.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: You wrote `text is actually type of array`. If it's an array (`text[]`) like in my sqlfiddle, all you need is `unnest()`. It's always better to provide a *table definition* in the question ...