# Find position(s) in array matching a given sub-array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, function

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE datasets.travel(path integer[], path_timediff double precision[]);

INSERT INTO datasets.travel
VALUES (array[50,49,49,49,49,50], array[NULL,438,12,496,17,435]);
```

I am looking for some kind of function or query in the PostgreSQL that for a given input `array[49,50]` will find the matching consecutive index values in `path` which is `[5,6]` and the corresponding element in `path_timediff` which is `435` in the example (array index `6`).

My ultimate purpose is to find all such occurrences of `[49,50]` in `path` and all the corresponding elements in `path_timediff`. How can I do that?

Comment: `array1[50,49,49,49,49.50]` is invalid. Can you clarify your example, please? And show your version of Postgres and the indexes you have.

Comment: Now it looks like your example does not match the description - unless I am missing something: `the index values in array1 which is [4,5]` .. looks like this should read `[5,6]`? Or explain how you match exactly ... (Also, your `INSERT` syntax is invalid as well.)

Comment: (array1 [50,49,49,49,49,50,49] ,array2[NULL,438,12,496,17,435,121]) here this array1 is basically a path values which is like 50 to 49 to 49 to 49 to 49 to 50.. now if i give a function like for example input (50,49) so the function find the first pair in the array1 and it search specific index in array2 which is index 1  and its value is 438. in array1 another pair it find which is [50,49] and its crosspounding index is 6 which value is 121 .now it must to add these two values returen me for this path..

Comment: exactly you are right Erwin...the values in the array2 must to be one more bcz array1[50] is the start point and when object reach from 50 to 49 then it take a travel time which is define in array2 which is [438] bcz  on rout 50 it does not have any travel time when it reach to next station which is for example 49 then it take a value like 438 and then it start again from 49 and reach to 49 so it take a time like 12 and so one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key in your table you did not show:

```
CREATE TABLE datasets.travel (
  travel_id     serial PRIMARY KEY
, path          integer[]
, path_timediff float8[]
);
```

Here is one way with [**`generate_subscripts()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS) in a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT t.travel_id, i+1 AS position, path_timediff[i+1] AS timediff
FROM  (SELECT * FROM datasets.travel WHERE path @> ARRAY[49,50]) t
     , generate_subscripts(t.path, 1) i
WHERE  path[i:i+1] = ARRAY[49,50];
```

This finds ***all*** matches, not just the first.

`i+1` works for a sub-array of length `2`. Generalize with `i + array_length(sub_array, 1) - 1`.

The subquery is not strictly necessary, but can use a GIN index on `(path)` for a fast pre-selection:

```
(SELECT * FROM datasets.travel WHERE path @> ARRAY[49,50])
```

Related:

- [How to access array internal index with postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246738/how-to-access-array-internal-index-with-postgresql/12250006#12250006)
- [Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Thanks Erwin.. Really appreciated for your sharing knowledge :)