# Unique index by another column for postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have this table (postgresql):

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(
 a TEXT,
 b TEXT
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_a_uniq_idx ON t(a);
```

I want to create unique constraint/index for `b` and `a` columns. But not simple `ADD CONSTRAINT t_ab UNIQUE (a, b)`. I want unique `b` by `a`:

```sql
INSERT INTO t(a,b) VALUES('123', null); -- this is ok
INSERT INTO t(a,b) VALUES('456', '123'); -- this is not ok, because duplicate '123'
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Why do I need this? For example, If I have `users` table and I want to create email changing feature, I need structure like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
 email TEXT,
 unconfirmed_email TEXT
 -- some other data
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_users_email_idx ON users(email);
```

User can set value into `unconfirmed_email` column, but only if this value don't used in `email` column.

Comment: More examples and explanation is needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated question

Comment: You update still leaves room for interpretation. What if a user sets his `email` to a value already present in `unconfirmed_email`? `email = unconfirmed_email` in the same row is allowed? `unconfirmed_email UNIQUE`?

Comment: No, it is not allowed. Every email must be unique by two columns.

Answer (score 1):

If uniqueness is needed across *both* columns, I think you have the wrong data model.  Instead of storing pairs on a single row, you should have two tables:

```
create table pairs (
    pairid int generated always as identity,
    . . .   -- more information about the pair, if needed
);

create table pairElements (
    pairElementId int generated always as identity,
    pairId int references pairs(pairid),
    which int check (which in (1, 2)),
    value text,
    unique (pairid, which)
);
```

Then the condition is simple:

```
create constraint unq_pairelements_value unique pairelements(value);
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. But I don't want to join two tables for every search request. Isn't there an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want a `UNIQUE` index over `a` and `b` combined.
Your update narrowed it down (`b` shall not exist in `a`). This solution is stricter.

### Solution

After trying and investigating quite a bit (see below!) I came up with this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT a_not_equal_b CHECK (a <> b);
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ab_unique
   EXCLUDE USING gist ((ARRAY[hashtext(COALESCE(a, ''))
                            , hashtext(COALESCE(b, ''))]) gist__int_ops WITH &&);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=60bc10839678a83cde8c5f40592d8212)*

Since the exclusion constraint won't currently (pg 12) work with `text[]`, I work with `int4[]` of hash values. `hashtext()` is the built-in hash function that's also used for hash-partitioning (among other uses). Seems perfect for the job.

The operator class `gist__int_ops` is provided by the additional module [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html), which has to be installed once per database. Its optional, the solution works with the default array operator class as well. Just drop `gist__int_ops` to fall back. But intarray is **faster**. Related:

- [How to create an index for elements of an array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867577/how-to-create-an-index-for-elements-of-an-array-in-postgresql/10868144#10868144)

#### Caveats

- **`int4`** may not be big enough to rule out hash collisions sufficiently. You might want to go with `bigint` instead. But that's more expensive and can't use the `gist__int_ops` operator class to improve performance. Your call.
- Unicode has the dismal property that equal strings can be encoded in different ways. If you work with Unicode (typical encoding UTF8) and use non-ASCII characters (and this matters to you), compare normalized forms to rule out such duplicates. The upcoming [Postgres 13 adds the function **`normalize()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) for that purpose. This is a general caveat of character type duplicates, though, not specific to my solution.
- **`NULL`** value is allowed, but **collides** with empty string (`''`). I would rather go with `NOT NULL` columns and drop `COALESCE()` from the expressions.

#### Obstacle course to an exclusion constraint

My first thought was: [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). But it falls through:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ab_unique EXCLUDE USING gist ((ARRAY[a,b]) WITH &&);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  data type text[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"
> HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
> ```

There is an [open TODO item](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#GIST) for this. Related:

- [ERROR: data type text[] has no default operator class for access method “gist”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185174/3684)

But can't we use a GIN index for `text[]`? Alas, no:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ab_unique EXCLUDE USING gin ((ARRAY[a,b]) WITH &&);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  access method "gin" does not support exclusion constraints
> ```

Why? [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)

> The access method must support `amgettuple` (see [Chapter 61](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexam.html)); at present this means GIN cannot be used.

It seems hard to implement, so don't hold your breath.

If `a` and `b` were `integer` columns, we could make it work with an integer array:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ab_unique EXCLUDE USING gist ((ARRAY[a,b]) WITH &&);
```

Or with the `gist__int_ops` operator class from the additional module [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.27.7) (typically faster):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT ab_unique EXCLUDE USING gist ((ARRAY[a,b]) gist__int_ops WITH &&);
```

To also forbid duplicates *within* the same row, add a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT a_not_equal_b CHECK (a <> b);
```

Remaining issue: Does work with `NULL` values.

#### Workaround

Add a helper table to store values from `a` and `b` in *one* column:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_ab(ab text PRIMARY KEY);
```

Main table, like you had it, plus FK constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  a text REFERENCES tbl_ab ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, b text REFERENCES tbl_ab ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Use a function like this to `INSERT`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_insert(_a text, _b text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH ins_ab AS (
   INSERT INTO tbl_ab(ab)
   SELECT _a WHERE _a IS NOT NULL  -- NULL is allowed (?)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT _b WHERE _b IS NOT NULL
   )
INSERT INTO tbl(a,b)
VALUES (_a, _b);
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IxHfnPXO)

Or implement a trigger to take care of it in the background.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_tbl_insbef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tbl_ab(ab)
   SELECT NEW.a WHERE NEW.a IS NOT NULL  -- NULL is allowed (?)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NEW.b WHERE NEW.b IS NOT NULL;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

CREATE TRIGGER tbl_insbef
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_tbl_insbef();

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2WCxFLk)

`NULL` handling can be changed as desired.

Either way, while the added (optional) FK constraints enforce that we can't sidestep the helper table `tbl_ab`, and allow to `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in `tbl_ab` to cascade, **you still need to project `UPDATE` and `DELETE` into the helper table** as well (or implement more triggers). Tricky corner cases, but there are solutions. Not going into this, after I found the solution above with an exclusion constraint using `hashtext()` ...

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer! I also thinking about exclude constraint. Too bad we can't use array for strings.

Comment: @Kroid: We can make it work with an integer array. Consider the added solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

While this leads to an interesting problem, I agree that the data could be modelled better - specifically, the column `unconfirmed_email` can be seen as combining two attributes: an association between an address and a user, which it shares with the `email` column; and a status of whether that address is confirmed, which is dependant on the combination of user and address, not on one or the other.

This implies that a new table should be extracted of `user_email_addresses`:

- user_id - foreign key to users
- email - non-nullable
- is_confirmed boolean

Interestingly, as often turns out to be the case, this extracted table has natural data that could be added:

- When was the address added?
- When was it confirmed?
- What is the verification code sent to the user?
- If the user is allowed multiple addresses, which is the primary, or which is to be used for a particular purpose?

---

We can now model various constraints on this table (using unique indexes in some cases because you can't specify `Where` on a unique constraint):

- Each user can only have one association (whether confirmed or not) with a particular e-mail address: `Constraint Unique ( user_id, email )`
- An e-mail address can only be confirmed for one user: `Unique Index On user_emails ( email ) Where is_confirmed Is True;`
- Each user can have only one confirmed address: `Unique Index On user_emails ( user_id ) Where is_confirmed Is True;`. You might want to adjust this to allow users to confirm multiple addresses, but have a single "primary" address.
- Each user can have only one *unconfirmed* address: `Unique Index On user_emails ( user_id ) Where is_confirmed Is False;`. This is implied in your current design, but may not actually be necessary.

---

This leaves us with a re-worded version of your original problem: how do we forbid *unconfirmed* rows with the same `email` as a *confirmed* row, but allow multiple identical *unconfirmed* rows.

One approach would be to use an `Exclude` constraint for rows where `email` matches, but `is_confirmed` *doesn't* match. The cast to `int` is necessary because creating the `gist` index on `boolean` fails.

```
Alter Table user_emails
Add Constraint unconfirmed_must_not_match_confirmed
Exclude Using gist ( 
    email With =,
    Cast(is_confirmed as Int) With <>
);
```

On its own, this would allow multiple copies of `email`, as long as they all had the same value of `is_confirmed`. But since we've already constrained against multiple rows where `is_confirmed Is True`, the only duplicates remaining will be where `is_confirmed Is False` on all matching rows.

---

Here is a db<>fiddle demonstrating the above design: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fd8e4e6a4cce79d9bc6bf07111e68df9